# access element from javascript function to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var id=0;// globel 
var elem=0;// globel
$.fn.myFunction = function(element){
    var sid = element.getAttribute('href'); 
    elem=element;   
    id=sid;
};
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.fn.myFunction();
 alert(id);
 alert(elem);
});
```

```html
<a href="#div-1" id="link-id-1" onclick="$.fn.myFunction(this);">Link 1</a><br>
<a href="#div-2" id="link-id-2" onclick="$.fn.myFunction(this);">Link 2</a><br>
<div id="div-1" class="hideAll">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div><br>
<div id="div-2" class="hideAll">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
```

This code is not working
I want to alert the `id` attributes `"link-id-1"` or `"link-id-2"` and `href` attributes `"#id-1"` or `"#id-2"` from the `javascript` function `(myFunction())` to `jquery` function

Comment: You are not passing `element` to the function?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: You are badly calling jq prototype method, it should be `$(this).myFunction();`. That's said, you shouldn't use obstrusive js, bind event using more relevant method, not onclick attribute

Comment: see http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Sir i want the href attribute and id attribute from that javascript function 
myFunction to that jquery function

Comment: $.fn.myFunction = function(element){

    var sid = element.getAttribute('href'); 
 alert(sid);
};
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.fn.myFunction();
 
});


this function working without passing anything

Comment: Again, what are you trying to do? Calling it on click, on document ready or both??? `from that javascript function myFunction to that jquery function` I still don't understand what you are saying?!

Comment: Sir,
Ijust want to pass those variable to jquery function If u can please help me to fix the issuw

Comment: So what you call jquery function is document ready handler??? And what you call js function is `$.fn.myFunction` method??? Please, read the link posted by Arun and don't use term that deosn't make sense... You have to show some minimalistic effort

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic error in your code. You are calling $.fn.myFunction on $(document).ready. It will not have a value for element.

Use this -

```
var id=0;// globel 
var elem=0;// globel
$.fn.myFunction = function(element){
var sid = element.href; 
elem=element;   
id=sid;
alert(id);
alert(elem);
};
```

Comment: But they still in that function 
I want to pass those id and sid to the jquery function and i want to add some effects on it

Comment: you can pick the href of element using jQuery like this -
$("#link-id-1")[0].href

Comment: can u pass that globel id and elem to $(document).ready(function(){
alert(id),
alert(elem);
});

Answer (score 0):

its better to use jquery simply rather than javascript for such kind of task

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert($("#link-id-1").attr("id")); 
        alert($("#link-id-2").attr("id"));
        alert($("#link-id-1").attr("href")); 
        alert($("#link-id-2").attr("href")); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <a href="#div-1" id="link-id-1">Link 1</a><br>
        <a href="#div-2" id="link-id-2">Link 2</a><br>
        <div id="div-1" class="hideAll">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div><br>
        <div id="div-2" class="hideAll">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</body>
</html>
```